# How to update the whole Backbone.js collection that in database?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have a collection (an object list) in database. I can fetch it like: `collectionModel.fetch()`
But then user changes something on that collection. When user clickes on save button, the whole collection list must be update in database. I thought maybe i can `delete()` the old one first and then `create()` it with new one but i could'n achive it. I can't use the `update()` method because in this case i should find which collection elements has changed but i want to update whole list. How can i do that? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a REST api in front of that database? That's how Backbone is made to work with. When your JavaScript code runs `model.save();` a PUT request is made to your api for that model.

You question is about saving the whole collection, for that if you want to remain within the default implementation of Backbone you will have to go over all the models in the collection and call save for each of them.

If you want to make one single request to your server you will have to implement a custom method inside your collection. Something like:

```
MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    saveAll: function() {
        var data = this.toJSON();
        return Backbone.$.ajax({
            data: { objects: data },
            url: '/url/in/your/server/to/update/db'
        });
    }
});
```

That's going to send the array of all models in your collection converted to JSON to your server.

Again, you want to have a RESTful API on the server side if you want to make your life with Backbone easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset collection you have to specify "reset" attribute.

```
collectionList.fetch({
    reset: true,

   ...
});
```

But I think it's better to just update it:

```
collectionList.fetch({
    remove: false,
    update: true,
    merge: true,

   ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but I had another approach so I thought I'd post it.

Sometimes my collections have a lot of data and the server doesn't get it all. I solved this by using one of the underscore methods that backbone collections have, `invoke` (also relies on jquery):

```js
MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  update: function(callback) {
    // Invoke the update method on all models
    $.when.apply($, this.invoke('update')).then(() => {
      // After complete call the callback method (if passsed)
      if(callback) {
        callback();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

You can use it by calling `collection.update()` when the collection has models in it. A similar method can be used for creating or deleting collections, and this should be modifiable to catch errors but I didn't account for that.